# What are the precise effects of the Fortune shrine?

Tags: diablo-iii

The randomly-found Fortune shrine "greatly" increases the change to find magic items and gold:

[image: fortune shrine text screenshot]

What does this "greatly" actually mean? What are the precise effects? And does it depend on character level / difficulty / anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fortune Shrine provides a **25%** bonus to Magic and Gold Find for the duration (2 minutes).

You'll see this in the message that appears on screen when you trigger the shrine.

Comment: Is it constant between difficulties?

Comment: I did a little double checking to confirm what I remembered seeing in game last night, and I've found nothing to indicate that it varies across difficulties in any way.

Comment: This, in contrast to the nephalem valor buff, falls like most other MF bonuses under the 300MF cap. (Meaning that when you are already on 300% MF from whatever source (paragon 100, mf on gear, mf on follower's gear) doesnt do anything)